# how to get value from SQL Dynamic Dependent Select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have follow a web site to made a Dynamic Dependent Select using SQL JQuery Ajax with PHP , and it's work !, but i would like to get the value from the second and third select box once i chosen , and auto fill in to the other input box. is that possible to do it ?

[look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ4HV.png)

if i selected all 3 select box and the data have shown (fetched from sql)
can i duplicate those 2 value to other input box and auto filled to the box???

Much thanks

code below

Index.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$country = '';
$query = "SELECT country FROM country_state_city GROUP BY country ORDER BY country ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $country .= '<option value="'.$row["country"].'">'.$row["country"].'</option>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">Dynamic Dependent Select Box using JQuery Ajax with PHP</h2><br /><br />
   <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control action">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php echo $country; ?>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control action">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.action').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != '')
  {
   var action = $(this).attr("id");
   var query = $(this).val();
   var result = '';
   if(action == "country")
   {
    result = 'state';
   }
   else
   {
    result = 'city';
   }
   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{action:action, query:query},
    success:function(data){
     $('#'+result).html(data);
    }
   })
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

fatch.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
 $output = '';
 if($_POST["action"] == "country")
 {
  $query = "SELECT state FROM country_state_city WHERE country = '".$_POST["query"]."' GROUP BY state";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  $output .= '<option value="">Select State</option>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["state"].'">'.$row["state"].'</option>';
  }
 }
 if($_POST["action"] == "state")
 {
  $query = "SELECT city FROM country_state_city WHERE state = '".$_POST["query"]."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  $output .= '<option value="">Select City</option>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["city"].'">'.$row["city"].'</option>';
  }
 }
 echo $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two input boxes and then use jquery to populate these on change of two select boxes like this.

```
<div>
    <input id="forState" />
    <input id="forCity" />    
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
      $('#state').change(function(){              
          console.log($("#state option:selected").val());
          $('#forState').val($("#state option:selected").val());
      } );

      $('#city').change(function(){              
          console.log($("#city option:selected").val());
          $('#forCity').val($("#city option:selected").val());
      } );
```

Comment: Can I get reference about price estimation using the dynamic dependent select box? like > USA (Country) -> Alaska (State) -> Shipping Cost : $80 @T.Shah